# Bundler HTTP works but not HTTPS; Network error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Upon running bundler with Gemfile source:
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

I am getting this error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Network error while fetching
https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/pg-0.14.0-x86mingw32.gemspec.rz
```

If I run the command specifying Gemfile source:
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

It runs well. Any ideas?

Using bundler (1.3.5).

Comment: have you set your http_proxy variable but not your https_proxy variable? :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that using and old ass version of rubygems will cause this.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this using some steps from the Bundler website (http://bundler.io/issues.html):

```
# remove user-specific gems and git repos 
rm -rf ~/.bundle/ ~/.gem/bundler/ ~/.gems/cache/bundler/  

# remove system-wide git repos and git checkouts 
rm -rf $GEM_HOME/bundler/ $GEM_HOME/cache/bundler/  

# remove project-specific settings 
rm -rf .bundle/  

# remove project-specific cached gems and repos 
rm -rf vendor/cache/  

# remove the saved resolve of the Gemfile 
rm -rf Gemfile.lock  

# uninstall the rubygems-bundler and open_gem gems 
rvm gemset use global # if using rvm 
gem uninstall rubygems-bundler open_gem  

# try to install one more time 
bundle install
```